# MovingAverage - not enough memory exception

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, memory

**Bug introduced after 9.0 and in 10.1 or earlier, and fixed in 10.4.0**

---

I'm running into an extremely bizarre issue that evades reproduction by means other, than repeating my actions verbatim.

**Please note, this question is NOT about digitizing a plot. It just describes the actions taken to reproduce an error, shown at the end.**

First take the following image:

[image: measured]

This is a plot I want to digitize. There are tiny little green marker points on the frame of the plot to map from image coordinates to plot coordinates. To filter out unnecessary pixels I define two functions:

```
Clear[fn1, fn2];
(fn1[#] = #) & /@ {{0., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}};
fn1[_] = {1., 1., 1.};
(fn2[#] = #) & /@ {{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.8}, {0., 1., 0.}};
fn2[_] = {1., 1., 1.};
```

They convert to white everything, except the four of the five main colors in this image: Black, White, Green `(0,1,0)` and either Red `(1,0,0)` or Blue `(0,0,0.8)`. Now import the image and get either one or the other curve:

```
tnse = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/08dE5.png"];
tnse1 = tnse // RemoveAlphaChannel // ImageApply[fn1, #] & // Erosion[#, 1] &;
tnse2 = tnse // RemoveAlphaChannel // ImageApply[fn2, #] & // Erosion[#, 1] &;
```

At this point I calculate the positions of the reference markers, etc., but this is not relevant to the question. So let's extract the datapoints from the plot like so:

```
curve1 = PixelValuePositions[
      Thinning[tnse1 // ColorNegate] // ColorNegate, {1., 0., 0.}] // 
     SortBy[First] // GatherBy[#, First] & // Mean /@ # &;
curve2 = PixelValuePositions[
      Thinning[tnse2 // ColorNegate] // ColorNegate, {0., 0., 0.8}] //
      SortBy[First] // GatherBy[#, First] & // Mean /@ # &;
```

And now I do

```
MovingAverage[curve1, 4]
```

> ```
> General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.
>
> Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException].
> ```

If I type

```
curve1
(* long list of pairs of numbers, Integer or Half-Integer *)
```

Then type `curve1 =` in the output cell like so:

[image: assign]

Thereby assigning to `curve1` whatever is returned by executing `curve1` then `MovingAverage` works properly.

Also this works properly:

```
MovingAverage[2 curve1, 4]/2
```

What is going on? I am running MMA 10.2.0.0 on Win 7x64 Professional. This problem was reproduced on a desktop computer and a laptop of similar configurations. Also it doesn't matter, whether I used the source file from my hard drive or the file uploaded to imgur. Also this problem came up when trying to digitize other images.

Comment: Does this still happen if you set `$HistoryLength = 0`?

Comment: @J.M. yes, regardless, before, or after all commands, a fresh kernel start, or whatever. It's persistent.

Comment: "What the hell is going on" - do we really need that kind of language around here?  :-P

Comment: @JasonB, Astonishment overwhelms me, so feel free to edit :-P

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening, but yet another workaround is to take the moving average of `N[curve1]`, so `MovingAverage[N@curve1, 4] // Rationalize` gives the desired result

Comment: @JasonB that much I gathered, but that's beside the point (it's experimental data anyway, I don't need rational numbers). What astounds, is that redefining `curve1` to itself (by copy-pasting its definition verbatim) fixes the problem. At this point I'm no longer interested in carrying out my task, but rather I morph into a fan of MMA and want to know... well... what the hell is going on :-)

Comment: Oh I know, I'm as obsessed with MMA as everyone else around here, lol.  I think prodding it to see what works and what spits back an error is productive in these cases.  For example, `Mean /@ Partition[curve1, 4, 1]` gives the desired results as well.  Using `TracePrint` shows that the last thing that goes through is a call to `ListCorrelate`, but the call itself gives no error when I copy and paste it into the notebook.

Comment: @JasonB if you replace the list in `ListCorrelate` with the symbol `curve1` it spits out the same error again though. That's the thing, the list itself is fine, but there's something wrong with the symbol...

Comment: Also there's a bunch of `$Failed` return along the way in the output of `TracePrint`, but that's probably not relevant if it chokes on the `ListCorrelate`

Comment: Right, I compared the results of the `TracePrint` on a successful clone, and on the failed one, and they are absolutely identical up to the point of failure.   Good luck on finding the problem with this one.

Comment: @bill-s I was trying to be funny above, hope you didn't edit that out on my behalf

Comment: @Jason B -- just removing excess verbiage.

Comment: As others have said this ends up calling `ListCorrelate` under the hood. Interestingly it fails just by using the first five elements of `curve1`. `ListCorrelate[{{1},{1},{1},{1}}, curve1[[;;5]]]`.

Comment: This is a bug that has already been fixed in the development version last month, thanks @DanielLichtblau !

Comment: I never even made the connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, this bug has been fixed in the just released Mathematica [10.4.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn104.html).

[image]