# How to digitize the figure?

Tags: plotting, digitization

Consider the following figure:

[image]

Could you please tell me how to extract the brown curve ($a\to KK\pi$) from it (i.e. the dependence Gamma[ma]?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but this should at least create an image that is easier to deal with: `With[{data = ImageData[RemoveAlphaChannel@img]}, Image[Unitize[data - Threaded[{130, 22, 4}/255]]]*Image[Unitize[data]]]`. `{130, 22, 4}` is the RGB value of the brown line

Comment: As I have mentioned in your previous question, this looks like a vector image. Please provide the source of your image – extracting curves directly from vector graphics is significantly easier than from a raster image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a curve selectable from a scaned image and convert it to a list of coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c) Also: [How can I extract trace points from an oscilloscope image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167445/how-can-i-extract-trace-points-from-an-oscilloscope-image)

Comment: @Domen : the source figure (.pdf) is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yjacqyjyhx2trx/a_rate.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source, rather than putting thie informaition in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming

```
pic="your image"
```

you could start with

```
dc = Rest@ DominantColors[pic]
Map[ListPlot[PixelValuePositions[bild, #, .1 (*Colordistance*) ], 
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> #] &, {dc[[-3]]} ][[1]]
```

[image]